# Issues while creating a session

Tags: php, session, mysqli

I am creating a user session but it's like code has gone wrong somewhere and doesn't hold session, I simply redirect user to a blank page where I echo user id of session holder to check whether it's working or not. Their is no problem with table or db as register page works fine and data gets stored in db. My `login.php`

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","findfriends") or die ("Connection not established");
?>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['login'])){ 
 $username = strip_tags(@$_POST['user_login']);
 $password = strip_tags(@$_POST['password_login']);    
 $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
 $row = $result->fetch_array(mysqli_both);
 session_start();
 $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['userid'];
 header("Location: test12.php");
 }
 ?>

    <h2>Already a member? Login Below</h2>
    <form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="user_login" size="25" placeholder="Username"/><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="password_login" size="30" placeholder="Passsword"/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="login" value="Login">
    </form>
```

`test.php` for checking session

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","findfriends") or die ("Connection not established");
?>
<?php  
session_start();
?>
<div style="margin-left:30px;margin-right:400px;border:1px solid #000;">
<h2>User id is:</h2>
<?php echo $_SESSION["userid"]; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you getting a completely blank page or is the HTML / H2 / other text still shown? If it's a completely blank page you are getting a server error, have you turned on error reporting?

Comment: h2 is there exactly what i typed "User id is" but user id is not echoed

Comment: As @AwaisTahir mentioned in the comments under his answer, try and do a `var_dump($row['userid']);` and see if it's get any value,

Comment: where to exactly place it in `login.php` and what part of code to remove from `login.php`

Comment: place it in login.php, just place it above the `header('Location:...');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make  `session_start();` your first line in the file

Comment: var_dump(  $row['userid']);  in login file to check what value is it hold

Comment: header("Location: test12.php") isn't this can cause error ? you are redirecting to test12 instead test

Comment: have u checked var_dump( $row['userid']); die(); ?

Comment: no where to exactly place it in login.php and which line to remove?

Comment: after this line in login page $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['userid'];

Comment: did that `test.php` still displays only h2 text

Comment: var_dump to debug  one other method write $_SESSION["userid"] = 1 ; instead $_SESSION["userid"] = $row['userid'];  to debug

Comment: so error is in your $row['userid']; variable do check it

Comment: or replace with this snippet  $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

Answer (score 0):

try by using $_SESSION['userid'] instead of $_SESSION["userid"].

Comment: even this isn't working what more the possible errors might be causing this problem?

Comment: You can check your session id with the function session_id(). If there is the same id in both files you could try by changin the name of the session variable (I had a problem with a session variable cause I was using a local varible like $userID and also a session variable $_SESSION['userID'])